# Non-repository management of TeXLive packages on Ubuntu

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

How do I install a package which is supplied by a publisher (like Springer or Elsevier)?
In MikTex (windows), I have to copy it into specified folder and than run some file which install the package. What are the corresponding actions in ubuntu with TeXLive?

Answer (score 9):

Put them into

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/springer
```

where `~` stands for your home. This for the `.cls` or `.sty` files; if there is a `.bst` file it should go into

```
~/texmf/bibtex/bst/springer
```

(choose a different name than `springer`, if you want to).

If you need to make the package available to all users on your system, the "local" tree is the correct place. On a terminal window type

```
kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL
```

and the answer is what you should substitute to `~/texmf` in the paths above. Copy the files and do

```
sudo texmklsr
```

Comment: Note that you need to run `texhash ~/texmf` if you already have a `~/texmf/ls-R` cache file. Newer TeX version do not need this file for the *user* `texmf` tree but will search it for requested files. However, if the `ls-R` file is present it will be used and no search is done. So you need to either update or delete this file after installing new files in this tree, otherwise they won't be found.

Comment: @Martin: this used to be true, but recent versions of Kpathsea just ignore the `ls-R` file if the tree is not mentionned in `TEXMFDBS`, precisely to avoid this issue. Anyway, it is best not to have a `ls-R`file in `~/texmf`, which is the default since TeX Live 2007.

Comment: Excellent answer! And you might want to reference http://tug.org/tds/tds.pdf for details on the `texmf` directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

May I point you to the excellent TeX FAQ, which answers [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-installthings) and other questions?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to put the files in `/usr/local/share/texmf` instead of `~/texmf` or `/usr/share/texmf`. Personally, think this is preferable because I don't like seeing the `texmf` directory all the time in my home directory. It also doesn't clutter the main tree. In case you're on a multiuser system then others can also use the packages. Naturally this demands `sudo` rights for your user.

Comment: Btw, this does not actually require sudo rights. It only requires write permission to the directory. You can give your user this permission once and for all so you don't need to use sudo every time you want to install a new package locally.

Answer (score 0):

You just copy the package (unziped) into the folder: 
**/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex**

After that you open the terminal in this folder and type:
**texhash**

You'll need root privileges to do that.
It's important read the documentation of the specific packages to find any important detail.

Comment: Using the main TeX tree is not recommended. An update to the distribution may destroy all changes.

Comment: I always use this tree to do serious work. And never had problems.

Comment: Well, you may have them when Ubuntu will shift to TeX Live 2010 (in 2013 or so).

Comment: @Jasper: let's wait and see. `:-)` The problem is not in the version, of course, but in the fact that the installation process *might* destroy personal changes. This won't happen to the local tree.