# How to create Custom Packages and import them in a TeX file

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages

I would like to create E-R diagrams. It can be done with TikZ. But a whole set of commands have to be written. And every time I have to draw a E-R diagram, I have to write them back. I would like to create a package and using my `\usepackage{}` command I would like to use the new macros defined. How do I create a custom package and update my TeXlive according to it?

Comment: There are two parts here. 1. How to write a package? For this you may search in this site. 2. How to make texline find your package? Again there are answers here suggesting you to make use of localtexmf folder. :)

Comment: For the package, you might find some useful hints in [Drawing relationships between elements of a database](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78357/13304), [Drawing a complete ER Diagram in Crow's foot style by TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141797/13304) and [TikZ ER diagrams: really can't underline keys?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135473/13304).

Comment: For creating a package: [How do I create a LaTeX package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34175/1952). for where to install it: [Non-repository management of TeXLive packages on Ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21459/1952), [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/1952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar for [styles](https://github.com/vermiculus/smcm-tex/blob/master/makefile) in graph theory.
Assuming you're on a UNIX-based system (or on Windows with Cygwin/MinGW installed),
  you can use the `install` tool coupled with a lesser-known use of `kpsewhich`:

```sh
SONI_DIR=`kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME`/tex/latex/soni/

install -m 755 -d $SONI_DIR
install -m 644 soni-er.sty $SONI_DIR
```

Just stick all of your TikZ styles into a proper `.sty` file (copy and paste will work fine) and run the above appropriately.
You'll then be able `\usepackage` your style from anywhere.

Comment: I have a Ubuntu System. Can you please elaborate with your example. I can get more clear cut idea